# Update Table With Results of SELECT SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having issues piecing this together. Can you guys help me fill in the blanks? I was trying to piece it together for other examples here on SO but I guess I am missing something completely? I guess I need to work on my SQL but I am hoping to subtract the sum aggregate function i have in the join from the value already in that table.

```
UPDATE [30 on hand].IVQTY001
SET [30 on hand].IVQTY001 = 
SELECT [30 on hand].Expr1 AS [Item#],
[30 on hand].IVQTY001 AS [001 OH],
Sum(dbo_ITEMS.QUANTO) AS [Order QTY],
FROM dbo_ITEMS INNER JOIN [30 on hand] ON dbo_ITEMS.ITEM = [30 on hand].Expr1
WHERE ((dbo_ITEMS.ORDERNO) Between X AND Y
GROUP BY [30 on hand].Expr1, [30 on hand].IVQTY001;
```

Answer (score 0):

A subquery needs to be in parentheses.  I'm not 100% sure what the intention of your query is, but I think it might be:

```
UPDATE [30 on hand]
    SET [30 on hand].IVQTY001 = (SELECT Sum(dbo_ITEMS.QUANTO) AS [Order QTY],
                                 FROM dbo_ITEMS 
                                 WHERE dbo_ITEMS.ITEM = [30 on hand].Expr1 AND
                                       dbo_ITEMS.ORDERNO Between X AND Y
                                );
```

Comment: it might be bad code. However the sub query needs to be join because the one table associates ITEMID by a different name than the other table. Not only that I want the new value to be SUM( IVQTY where [30 on hand].Expr1 - dbo_ITEMS.ITEM)